# Python: Searching for a data in JSON

Tags: python, json, api, dictionary

How to extract data of specific district (e.g. Nicobars, North and Middle Andaman...) from https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json
I need to extract Active just by searching for the district name.
Right now I'm extracting it this way:

```
url='https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = r.read().decode()
js=json.loads(data)
print('Confirmed cases:', js[State_name]['districtData']["District_name"]['confirmed'])
```

I don't want to specify state name every time.

Comment: You should edit the question to be more clear on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
url= 'https://api.covid19india.org/state_district_wise.json'  
r = urllib.request.urlopen(url)  
data = r.read().decode()  
js = json.loads(data)  

district = "Prakasam" 

for state, value in js.items():  
    if not district in value['districtData'].keys(): 
        continue 
      
    value = value['districtData'][district] 

    print(f"State: {state}") 
    print(f"* District: {district}")  
    print(f"** Active: {value['active']}")  
    print(f"** Confirmed: {value['confirmed']}")
```

Comment: This is returning all the district values, I want to search for a specific district by its name

Comment: This works. If you don't mind can you explain what's actually happening here, I didn't understand

Comment: I just iterate through json keys (states, then districts) and skip districts that don’t match ‘district’ variable’s value